# How to host modern console application on legacy serial COM device in Windows

Tags: windows-8, usb, serial-port

**EDIT:** Changed primary example from Zork Dungeon to the default OS shell.

I have a console application running on a modern machine. I also have an Apple //e with a Super Serial Card, which allows it to function as a dumb terminal via a serial COM connection (details are useless beyond that). I can connect these two devices just fine using a USB Serial port.

When the modern machine has Linux booted, by configuring COM settings and giving myself rights to the group the device file belongs to, I can run

```
$ bash </dev/ttyUSB1 >/dev/ttyUSB1 2>/dev/ttyUSB1
```

and get a bash session on the Apple - the Linux machine acts as server and runs the program, but input and output go to the Apple, which is a simple client. This also works with more dedicated programs, such as `dungeon` (Zork).

How do I do the same thing in Windows? Obviously, I cannot replicate the above solution exactly since Windows only lets me have a `COM` port open in one place at a time - running the Windows analogue of the above command,

```
C:\> cmd <COM4 >COM4 2>COM4
```

gives me an Access Denied error.

I can send data to the COM port:

```
C:\> echo "Hello" >COM4
```

and read raw input (including control and escape characters!) from the COM port:

```
C:\> type <COM4
```

but I cannot do both at the same time, in the same or separate processes.

I tried using PuTTY and RealTerm, but both of those only let me operate the Apple from the Windows machine, which proves the connection works but is exactly the opposite direction of what I want. How do I host a Windows console application for access from a connected terminal?

Comment: "lets me have a COM port open" - I am 100% sure that is false.  I just got done working on a project where I was opening multiple COM ports on a single machine using Putty and internally within the project itself.

Comment: @Ramhound I can open multiple COM ports easily. I just can't have the *same* COM port open with more than one file handle, and no software suite I've found that can communicate bidirectionally with the COM port can send and receive data from an external program.

Comment: That is correct and to be expected...

Comment: @Ramhound. Yes. But these terminal applications like PuTTY and RealTerm are doing something to enable bidirectional communication with the COM port (albeit in the wrong direction). My question is, how do I get it in the right direction?

Comment: How can a bidirectional COM connection be connected in the wrong direction?  How can a COM connection not be bidirectional, serial COM connections must community both ways, in order for them to work

Comment: @Ramhound - I meant that it's the wrong relationship hierarchy - the computer that should be the client is the server, and vice versa.

Comment: Be sure what you say is what you mean, because, I am even more confused after you attempted to clarify yourself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33187/discussion-between-compynerd255-and-ramhound).

Answer (score 1):

> **Edit:** "Re-answered" after question clarification

According to [Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) (I can't find `Using command redirection operators` section for Windows newer than XP):

> Duplicating handles
>
> The & redirection operator duplicates output or input from one specified handle to another specified handle. For example, to send dir output to File.txt and send the error output to File.txt, type:
>
> dir>c:\file.txt 2>&1
>
> When you duplicate a handle, you duplicate all characteristics of the original occurrence of the handle. For example, if a handle has write-only access, all duplicates of that handle have write-only access. You cannot duplicate a handle with read-only access into a handle with write-only access.

So good news is:

- You can change `<COM4 >COM4 2>COM4` to `<COM4 >&1 2>&1`.

Bad news is:

- You are mixing read-only `<COM4` and write-only `>&1 2>&1` handle access requirements and you are changing `Access Denied` to `The handle could not be duplicated during redirection of handle 1`.

If you change:

- `<COM4 >&1 2>&1` to `>COM4 2>&1 <&1` (read-only and write-only are still mixed) which works and give you usable `STDOUT` and `STDERR`, but `STDIN` still seems* to be broken. (*)*I have done few tests, but it seems that `STDIN` don't work...*

However I can see one workaround to fix it:

- Use [`com0com` null-modem emulator](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/) and define 3 virtual port pairs:

  - `COM_O` - `COM_O4` for `STDOUT`;
  - `COM_E` - `COM_E4` for `STDERR`;
  - `COM_I` - `COM_I4` for `STDIN`.
- Make a serial hub with `hub4com.exe` (`com0com` part) from `COM_O4`, `COM_E4`, `COM_I4` and `COM4`:

  - `hub4com.exe --route=0:1 --route=2,3:0 --baud=19200 --data=8 --parity=no --stop=1 --octs=off --odsr=off --ox=off --ix=off --idsr=off --ito=0 \\.\COM4 \\.\COM_I4 \\.\COM_E4 \\.\COM_O4`
  - Remember to setup proper (you own) transmission parameters: `--baud`...
- And `<\\.\COM_I >\\.\COM_O 2>\\.\COM_E` form command-line.

---

Finally, for:

```
hub4com.exe --route=0:1 --route=2,3:0 --octs=off \\.\COM4 \\.\COM_I4 \\.\COM_E4 \\.\COM_O4
```

and:

```
cmd <\\.\COM_I >\\.\COM_O 2>\\.\COM_E
```

you have a Windows command-line on `COM4` on `19200 8N1`...

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear - I have edited the post. The same issue also happens with `cmd` and other programs that run in the Windows command prompt just fine, and that is what I'm trying to accomplish here.

Comment: @Compynerd255 I have updated answer a bit...

Comment: Thank you very much - this seems promising. However, do you think you'd be able to elucidate what commands you're using to create the hub? I'm not able to get the hub to work with an additional test port.

Comment: @Compynerd255 Extended with hub4com command...

Comment: @Compynerd255 Is it working for you?

Comment: Oh, sorry for not responding. I have yet to test it with my actual COM device (Apple //ees are pretty unwieldy and need several plugs), but I created a fourth virtual port pair and can only get one of output or input to work. I'll keep trying, though.